Embedding ShadcnUI combobox in Wordpress page - when clicking page scrolls up
I build a very simple NextJS app using a combobox from ShadCN UI.
Code can be found here but it's not interesting: https://github.com/santivdt/ais-batch-numbers
I embedded this app with an iFrame on a Wordpress website: https://authenticindigenousseafood.ca/traceability/
Whenever you click the combobox to start your search the page scrolls up.
I am not sure if this is related to Wordpress/iFrames, or to something with default behaviour of the combobox. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
